# change the number of checkboxes in HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I would have a group of checkboxes in the HTML page but the number of checkboxed depends on a uploaded file.

For example, suppose that the uploaded file is a data set which contains five columns. Thus automatically  there should be five checkboxes on the website and user can select columns by checking the corresponding boxed.

I am thinking about how to use javascript (or jQuery) to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the files array using $('input[name^="name_of_file_input"]')[0].files, and then count the number of files, create the html inside a loop (whose max value to the files count) for the check boxes and render into your form. Hope it helps !

for example

```
var checkboxes = "";
for(var i = 0;i<=5;i++){
   checkboxes += "<input type='checkbox' name=''/>";
}
$("#id_where_you_will_put_the_checkboxes").html(checkboxes);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! Can you write a brief demo to use a loop to create say, 5, check boxes?

Comment: see my edited answer !

Answer (score 0):

you can add automatically checkboxes using this code

```
var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
checkbox.type = "checkbox";
checkbox.name = "";
checkbox.value = "";
checkbox.id = "";
var label = document.createElement('label')
label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('text for label after checkbox'));

element.appendChild(checkbox);
elemnt.appendChild(label);
```

and you can respond to click event by wrapping this code in

```
elem.onclick = function(){
}
```

Comment: Where is your demo?!!

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your help! Can you tell me how to write a loop to create, say 5, check boxes?